# Rxjs distinctUntilChanged with timer

Tags: rxjs

Is there a way to add a timer to distinctUntilChanged?

In rxjs 6

```
of(1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6)
  .pipe(distinctUntilChanged)
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x)
```

My question is, is there a way to add a timer so that repeated values will emit if they fall outside the time range but will be ignored if they fall within the time range.

Like if the say the timer is set to 1000 (1s), in this case `interval(1000)` and a repeated value is emitted within the 1s it will be ignore but if after the interval (1s) it should be allowed through. I hope am making sense here

Also if there's a better way to do it without `distinctUntilChanged` i will gladly welcome that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to emit if value changed or not emition for more than n milliseconds ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun for repeated values emit if the timer has run out

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one of the very rare occasions where `windowTime` is useful. `windowTime` creates a new Subject after a period of time that is passed further (so called higher-order Observable). Then you can use `concatMap` to chain it with `distinctUntilChanged`. This all means you'll create a new `distinctUntilChanged` every 1s:

```
const subject = new Subject();

subject
  .pipe(
    windowTime(1000),
    concatMap(obs => obs.pipe(distinctUntilChanged())),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);

subject.next(1);
subject.next(2);

setTimeout(() => subject.next(2), 1200);
```

See live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-pcmrzz?file=index.ts

Comment: brilliant just brilliant. Thanks a lot

Comment: it looks like the windowTime will run the whole time. Can i stop it or is that by design

Comment: @phacic That's true, it keeps creating new windows every 1s. You want to stop it how or when?

Answer (score 3):

Just append a date property to the previous map output, and compare it in the distinctUntilChanged, and pluck out the date property after :)

```
fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
    .pipe(
        map(e => ({key: e.key, time: Date.now()})),
        distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => (a.key == b.key) && (a.time > b.time - 500)),
        pluck('key')
    )
```

Comment: Nice! This one is simple and straight forward without the added overhead of a timer window or created seperate observables.

Answer (score 1):

`skipUntil` should do what you are looking for, if I understood right.

This can be an example

```
const obs = interval(100).pipe(
    tap(d => console.log('data emitted', d)),
    take(10),
);


obs
.pipe(
    skipUntil(interval(500).pipe(take(1)))
)
.subscribe(
    data => console.log('data read in the subscription', data)
)
```

Comment: I like how you used `skipUtil` with interval. It could work just that i will need to filter out repeated values. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It was nice to think about this issue, I ended up using a [merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) of the two following observables :

The simple distincUntilChanged for the new values :

```
const untilChanged$ = sharedRequest$
 .pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
```

A gap filler that will resend the last value every n milliseconds if no new value was received :

```
const gapFiller$ = untilChanged$
 .pipe(switchMap(a => interval(3000)
 .pipe(mapTo('Resend - ' + a))));
```

This Observable will create a new `interval` every time the `untilChanged$` sends a new value.

[Here is the stackblitz demonstration](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-50928751), open the browsers console instead of the stackblitz console to have the time between each fire. I added a 'Resend' string before the values sent by the `gapFiller$` Observable.

Comment: this shows there is more than one way to go by an issues. Thanks